# 2011-01-22T03:41:02+0000 - What is time zone?

Tags: javascript, datetime

`2011-01-22T03:41:02+0000` - What time zone is for that string?

And how can I get the current time in this time zone in javascript?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you asking what the time zone is for that string or what time zones are in general?

Comment: That is `GMT+00:00` or `UTC+00:00`. There is no difference in both.

Comment: [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+0000 is GMT/UTC. Given the date, that's a valid date/time in the GMT timezone (UK, at least part of Portugal, parts of Africa, ...).

> And how can I get the current time in this time zone in javascript?

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. You can get the *current* time in UTC like this:

```
var dt = new Date();
console.log(dt.toISOString());
```

Comment: Lisbon too. Madeira as well (?).

Comment: Actually, it's only valid in the UK for part of the year - when BST is not in effect.  Thats why +0000 is usually considered just a "time zone offset", and not a "time zone".  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson: That's why I said "***Given the date**, that's a valid date/time in the GMT timezone..."*